# Simple mysql regular expression query

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I want to select all values where the first character in a column is equal to a particular character, and the second character is numeric [0-9] but can't quite get the syntax.

```
select * from table where var LIKE ("r*")
```

Thanks,

Comment: select * from table where var LIKE ("r%")

Comment: ``LIKE`` doesn't support regular expressions. Use ``regexp`` to match against regular expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from table where var LIKE "r%"
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like

To check is the second character numeric, you'll have to use `REGEXP`:

```
select * from table where var REGEXP "^r[0-9]"
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp

Comment: Thanks, appreciate help on an intro question

Answer (score 1):

Simple :)

```
select * from table where var LIKE 'r%'
```

or even better

```
select * from table where lower(var) LIKE 'r%'
```

EDIT :

```
select * from table where var REGEXP "^r[0-9]"
```

Comment: Thanks -- minor update to the question to have a second character as numeric -- would appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

`LIKE` recognises two wildcard characters:

- `_` matches any single character
- `%` matches any number of characters

So in this case, you need to use the following:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `var` LIKE 'r%'
```

EDIT:

If you want to allow characters in a certain range (ie. numbers) then that is beyond the scope of `LIKE` in right in the field of `REGEXP`:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `var` REGEXP '^r[0-9]'
```

Note that regexes are a little different. They can match anywhere in the string, so the `^` tells it to only look at the beginning, and there's no need to tell it "followed by anything" as you would with `LIKE`.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware of the syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE var LIKE 'r%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a % rather than a *

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE var LIKE "r%"
```